# Bison nonassociative precedence rule

Tags: parsing, grammar, bison

I am trying to enforce some parsing errors by defining a non-associative precedence.
Here is part of my grammar file:

```
Comparison :
    Value ComparisonOp Value 
    {
        $2->Left($1);
        $2->Right($3);
        $$ = $2;
    } 
    ;
```

Expressions like 1 = 2 should parse, but expressions like 1 = 2 = 3 are not allowed in the grammar. To accommodate this, I tried to make my operator non associative as follows:

```
%nonassoc NONASSOCIATIVE
.
.(rest of the grammar)
.
Comparison :
    Value ComparisonOp Value %prec NONASSOCIATIVE
    {
        $2->Left($1);
        $2->Right($3);
        $$ = $2;
    } 
    ;
```

1 = 2 = 3 still passes, Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the associativity of the `ComparisonOp` token(s).  Either

```
%nonassoc ComparisonOp NONASSOCIATIVE
```

if `ComparisonOp` is a token or something like

```
%nonassoc '=' '<' '>' NOT_EQUAL GREATOR_OR_EQUAL LESS_OR_EQUAL NONASSOCIATIVE
```

if you have mulitple tokens and `ComparisonOp` is a rule that expands to any of them

---

As a concrete example, the following works exactly like you are requesting:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int yylex();
void yyerror(const char *);
%}
%nonassoc '=' '<' '>' CMPOP
%left '+' '-' ADDOP
%left '*' '/' '%' MULOP
%token VALUE
%%
expr: expr cmp_op expr %prec CMPOP
    | expr add_op expr %prec ADDOP
    | expr mul_op expr %prec MULOP
    | VALUE
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;
cmp_op: '=' | '<' | '>' | '<' '=' | '>' '=' | '<' '>' ;
add_op: '+' | '-' ;
mul_op: '*' | '/' | '%' ;
%%
int main() { return yyparse(); }
int yylex() {
    int ch;
    while(isspace(ch = getchar()));
    if (isdigit(ch)) return VALUE;
    return ch;
}
void yyerror(const char *err) { fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", err); }
```

so if you are having other problems, try posting an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the actual problem you are having...

Comment: ComparisonOp is a rule, that expands to tokens EQ, NEQ, I tried adding precedence rules for these tokens but apparently the precedence does not propagate to the parent rule

Comment: You need to set the precedence properly on both the rules and the tokens -- bison precedence resolution works by comparing the precedence of a rule to be reduced with that of a token to be shifted.  If you set only one or the other, nothing will happen.

Comment: I have done both, still it does not work. One subtly here is that in the rule for Value I have

Comment: Sorry went pass the 5 minute edit time limit. --> I have done both actually, still it does not work. One subtly here is that in the rule for Value I have `Value : MathExpression` + other things, and `MathExpression : Comparison` + other things. I do not want the first Comparison (1 = 2 ) to reduce to a value and allow for another comparison  (1= 2) = 3.

Comment: Problem solved Chris thanks,  I was doing `%nonassoc '=' '<' '>'` and  `%nonassoc CMPOP` on two separate lines.